# Inserting European language words (special characters) into a snowflake table from Java code but data is not inserted as it is, but manual insert has

Tags: java, jdbc, character-encoding, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, special-characters

I need to Insert European language words (which has special characters) into a snowflake table from Java code but data is not inserted as it is, but when I do manual insert it is working. I tried assigning collate 'UTF' or collate specific country code in the table but no luck. is any character encoding available to set in snowflake jdbc url ? please help. thanks.

Comment: Well to help debug, you can look at the history to see how the insert from Java code was formed. And even turn that SQL into base64, to avoid the history command fiddling with the input, and then review the SQL in notepad++ or some other tool. And compare that to the WebUI insert commands that "worked"

Comment: Can you share your Java code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.